# How can i insert current date on php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

i am trying to insert current date, exp date with 25 day interval and email fly date with 20 day interval.but these data not save in the database.what can be the reason?

Here is my code

```
<?php

include_once 'dbconnect.php';

if(isset($_POST['btn-signup']))
{
    $reqnum = $_POST['reqnum'];
    $Mnumber = $_POST['Mnumber'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $emailErr = "Invalid email format";
    }

    $fname = $_POST['fname'];
    $address = $_POST['address'];
    $sitename = $_POST['sitename'];
    $payment = $_POST['payment'];
    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $descr = $_POST['descr'];
    $regdate = $_POST['reg_date'];
    $exp_date =$_POST['exp_date'];
    $emailflydate = $_POST['emailflydate'];

    //if()
    //{
    $new_fname= $_POST['sitename'];
    $xxx = mysql_query("SELECT sitename FROM gotest WHERE sitename = '$new_fname'")or die(mysql_error());
    $yyy = mysql_fetch_row($xxx);

    if(mysql_num_rows($xxx) > 0)
    {
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('gdrhh !')</script>";

    }
    else
    {
        $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO gotest(Mnumber,email,fname,address,sitename,reqnum,payment,title,descr,reg_date,exp_date,emailflydate) VALUES('$Mnumber','$email','$fname','$address','$sitename','$reqnum','$payment','$title','$descr', CURDATE(), DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 25 DAY ), DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 20 DAY ))");

        $r = mysql_insert_id();


    }

}

?>
```

Comment: Is it working if you try in phpmyadmin ? Also check if your else condition is working or not

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not use the [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It’s so awful and dangerous that it was removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) explains best practices. Your user parameters are **not** [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) and there are [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) that can be exploited.

Comment: use now(). IT will help you.

Comment: @RuchishParikh when now () used it stored reg_date succesfully but not other dates with interval

Comment: then use DATE_ADD() and add time interval in curdate()

Answer (score 2):

You can always insert `NOW()` or `UTC_TIMESTAMP()` if you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

Try It:-

```
<?php

include_once 'dbconnect.php';

if(isset($_POST['btn-signup']))
{
    $reqnum = $_POST['reqnum'];
    $Mnumber = $_POST['Mnumber'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $emailErr = "Invalid email format";
    }

    $fname = $_POST['fname'];
    $address = $_POST['address'];
    $sitename = $_POST['sitename'];
    $payment = $_POST['payment'];
    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $descr = $_POST['descr'];
    $regdate = $_POST['reg_date'];
    $exp_date =$_POST['exp_date'];
    $emailflydate = $_POST['emailflydate'];

    //if()
    //{
    $new_fname= $_POST['sitename'];
    $xxx = mysql_query("SELECT sitename FROM gotest WHERE sitename = '$new_fname'")or die(mysql_error());
    $yyy = mysql_fetch_row($xxx);

    if(mysql_num_rows($xxx) > 0)
    {
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('gdrhh !')</script>";

    }
    else
    {
        $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO gotest(Mnumber,email,fname,address,sitename,reqnum,payment,title,descr,reg_date,exp_date,emailflydate) VALUES('$Mnumber','$email','$fname','$address','$sitename','$reqnum','$payment','$title','$descr', '".date('Y-m-d h:i:s')."', '".date('Y-m-d h:i:s')."', INTERVAL 25 DAY ), DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 20 DAY ))");

        $r = mysql_insert_id();


    }

}

?>
```